# "global name is not defined" - in maya python

Tags: python, maya

I'm writing a simple tool for Maya and I try to call a basic function within another one. But I always get: `global name "baseShape" is not defined`.

Here is a snippet of my code with the error:

```
class correctiveShaper():
    def __init__(self):
        #class variable
         self.app = {}

        #call on the build UI
         self.buildUI()

    def buildUI(self, *args):
        cmds.separator(h=30)
        cmds.button(label="Create Shape", w=295, h=30, al="right", c= baseShape)

    def baseShape (self, *args) : 
        self.app["sel"]=cmds.ls(sl=True)[0]
```

Python won't let me execute the `c = baseShape` command in `def buildUI` and I don't know why.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `self` to reference methods on the instance:

```
cmds.button(label="Create Shape", w=295, h=30, al="right", c=self.baseShape)
```

Methods are *not globals*. By using `self.baseShape` you get a *bound method*, an object that knows how to pass in the instance to the method when called.